# How can I adjust the size of a KivyMD Tabs' content?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to build three tabs using KivyMD, but when I add a content to each MDTabsBase, the contents always take the same space. I tried a lot changing its size so the content takes the whole box, but just doesn't work.

Here is how the content looks like:

[image]

And the code:

```
Screen:
    name: 'itemscad_food'
    BoxLayout:
        id: boxcad
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            id: toolcad
            title: "Item Register"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            anchor_title: 'justify'
            left_action_items: [['menu-left', lambda x: app.back_button()]]
        BoxLayout:
            id: tabox
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDTabs:
                id: itemstab
                tab_display_mode: 'text'            
                        
                MDTabsBase:
                    id: ingr_tab
                    name: 'ingredients'
                    text: "Ingredientes"                                                
                        
                MDTabsBase:
                    id: prod_tab
                    name: 'products'
                    text: "Products"
                    MyLabel:
                        text: 'Strawberry Cake'
                    MyLabel:
                        text: 'Chocolate Cake'
                            
                MDTabsBase:
                    id: pack_tab
                    name: 'packs'
                    text: "Pacotes"
```

Yes, I am only using KV Language for this. I'm building most of App's layout on it and so far it's all good, except for this :/

I also tried to do it in another way:

- Building the tabs content separately from the MDTabs class, but this way I can't seem to find a way to make different contents for each Tab.

Here is how it looks like the other way:

[image]

And the code:

```
    Screen: 
        name: 'itemscad_food'
        BoxLayout:
            id: boxcad
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                id: toolcad
                title: "Item Register"
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                anchor_title: 'justify'
                left_action_items: [['menu-left', lambda x: app.back_button()]]
            BoxLayout:
                id: tabox
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MDTabs:
                    id: itemstab
                    tab_display_mode: 'text'            
                        
                    MDTabsBase:
                        id: ingr_tab
                        name: 'ingredients'
                        text: "Ingredientes"                                                
                        
                    MDTabsBase:
                        id: prod_tab
                        name: 'products'
                        text: "Products"
                            
                    MDTabsBase:
                        id: pack_tab
                        name: 'packs'
                        text: "Pacotes"
                        
            FloatLayout:       
                BoxLayout:
                    id: listbox
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: boxcad.height - (toolcad.height + itemstab.tab_bar_height)
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    ScrollView:
                        do_scroll_x: False
                        MDList:     
                            OneLineRightIconListItem:
                                text: 'Strawberry Cake'
                                MyListDeleteIcon:
                                    icon: 'trash-can'
                            OneLineRightIconListItem:
                                text: 'Chocolate Cake'
                                MyListDeleteIcon:
                                    icon: 'trash-can'
                            OneLineRightIconListItem:
                                text: 'Vanilla Cake'
                                MyListDeleteIcon:
                                    icon: 'trash-can'
                            ...
```

Can anyone give me ideas on this?

I am so sorry for any mistakes, as I'm still getting used to coding xD

Thanks anyway!!!

Answer (score 1):

create a class that will inherit from FloatLayout and MDTabsBase in your python file then you can place your Labels on any position you want`enter code here`

```py
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MyTab(FloatLayout,MDTabsBase):

        pass

class MyTab1(FloatLayout,MDTabsBase):

        pass
```

acess the class using the kivy file under Tab and then give it the nice look you like

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option allow_stretch and set it to True under MDTabs. I'm sorry it seems I can't indent the codes.

```
MDTabs:
    id: itemstab
    tab_display_mode: 'text'
    allow_stretch: True
```